# ~ipad and ~iphone and hosting content with apple

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have two questions which i cant find searching.

I'm making a photo app with lots of photos. I'm naming them ~iphone and ~ipad with different res. And want to upload one binary as a universal app. When running the app on my test device the app seems to be installed with all the images, since its 110mb and the images are around that size. Is it different when uploading the binary to the appstore or is it an other way to do it?

Second question is regarding uploading the content to apples servers. Should I have both ~iphone and ~ipad images in one content file or should I upload them separately? If separately, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should be two questions

1) The binary you upload to Apple will be the same size.

2) If it's to be a universal app then they have to be in one content file.